How to interpret the output for nested random factors in glmer and how to put it in a table
I am looking at an alternation of a character in a word using a congressional Hansard. I have a binary outcome dependent variable (kuni), the date of the meeting expressed as the standardized number of days since 1949/05/31 (days_cnt2) as the only fixed variable, and two random factors for meeting (meetid) and word (morphid). Since each meeting is specific to a specific day, the meeting variable is nested under days_cnt2. Thus, the model looks like kuni~days_cnt2+(1+days_cnt2|morphid)+(1|days_cnt2/meetid). I ran a binomial logistic regression with glmer, and got the following output:
Random effects:
 Groups           Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 meetid:days_cnt2 (Intercept) 14.0795  3.7523       
 days_cnt2        (Intercept) 26.7335  5.1704       
 morphid          (Intercept)  3.3889  1.8409       
                  days_cnt2    0.2283  0.4778   0.71
Number of obs: 748186, groups:  
meetid:days_cnt2, 12034; days_cnt2, 1189; morphid, 301

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -9.2793     0.3416  -27.16   <2e-16 ***
days_cnt2   -11.8274     0.3045  -38.84   <2e-16 ***

The ICC values are:
Adjusted ICC: 0.931
Unadjusted ICC: 0.237
I have several questions for this result:

Am I right in saying word (morphid) has less effect than meeting (meetid), based on the fact that the former has only about half SD (1.8409) of the latter (3.7523)?

How should I interpret the days_cnt2 parameter values in the random effects section?

When publishing the result in a paper, should I include the values for all of the four effects (meetid:days_cnt2, days_cnt2, morphid, and days_cnt2) or should I skip days_cnt2?

Which package would be the best choice for formatting the result like above in a table?


Thanks in advance
The exact glmer command I used is:
result <- glmer(kuni~days_cnt2 + (1+days_cnt2|morphid) + (1|days_cnt2/meetid), 
                data=glmmdata6, family=binomial, 
                control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5))


What is a * congressional Hansard*?

kjetil  It's a record of a congress. It has all the proceedings of the meetings held at the congress.
